# eclipse using JavascriptInterface triggering toast from javascript

Tags: java, javascript, android, webview, toast

hello i am trying for few days in few ways to get this working and i failed if someone can please help me find out what i'm doing wrong, all i want is that when i press the button it will show the javascript text in Toast:

my java main:

```
package com.callphone;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        String content = "file:///android_asset/www/mypage.html";
        WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.mybrowser);
        WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
        webView.loadUrl(content);
        webView.addJavascriptInterface(new MyJavaScriptInterface(this), "AndroidFunction");
    }
        public class MyJavaScriptInterface {
             Context mContext;

                MyJavaScriptInterface(Context c) {
                    mContext = c;
                }
                public void showToast(String toast){
                    Toast.makeText(mContext, toast, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
    }

   }
```

my xml:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:orientation="vertical"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   >
<WebView
   android:id="@+id/mybrowser"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  />

</LinearLayout>
```

my html:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="index.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>What's your number</h1>
<button onclick="shownumber('55555')">show number</button>
</body>
</html>
```

and my javascript:

`function shownumber(number) {
AndroidFunction.showToast(number);
}`

when i change the javascript to alert it display the alert, so i figure the problem with the AndroidFunction

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [doucmentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#addJavascriptInterface%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.String%29) you are missing the annotation @JavascriptInterface in your `MyJavaScriptInterface`

This should work:

```
public class MyJavaScriptInterface {
             Context mContext;

                MyJavaScriptInterface(Context c) {
                    mContext = c;
                }
                @JavascriptInterface
                public void showToast(String toast){
                    Toast.makeText(mContext, toast, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
    }
```